# Varnishlog log only specified IP

Tags: regex, varnish

I want to log varnish backend request which matches specified IP (for example 127.0.0.1).
So i have 
"varnishlog -b -I BereqHeader:X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1'"
Which actualy logs only the "BereqHeader:X-Forwarded-For:" part. I want to log full request, not only IP part.

That was first question, the second one is: how to disable loging empty request? I mean, if i have regex filter then i have a lot of request looking like this "*   << BeReq    >> 307454" and i obviously dont want to see them.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. Log the data by
varnishlog -b -I BereqHeader:'X-Forwarded-For: 123.215.32.76' -i [other tags to log] > file.varnishlog
and then grep it by
cat file.varnishlog | grep -Pzo '* {3}<< BeReq {4}>>.*\n-   BereqHeader.+\n(-.*\n)*' 
which'll give us expected results.